# Ruby on Rails where query with relations and updated_at compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use where query with relationships and updated_at compare.

When I send this query with updated_at params, I want to fetch only the latest reasons filtered by updated_at date, but it filters with project's updated_at, not by reasons updated_at.

How can I fix this to get reasons data with updated_at filter?

@Getting reasons with updated_at filter

```
https://server.com/api/v1/entries?updated_at=2016-05-02T01:12:57.204Z
```

@Model

```
User
  has_many :projects
  has_many :reasons, through: :projects

Project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reasons

Reasons
  belongs_to :project
```

@Reasons Controllers

```
  # GET /reasons
  def index
    reasons     = current_user.reasons
    updated_at  = params[:updated_at]

    # Filter with updated_at for reloading from mobile app
    if updated_at.present?

      # This is my first try, but it shows error because of relations
      # reasons = reasons.where("updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))      

      # This shows reasons data, but it only compares updated_at in Project data, not reasons data...
      reasons = reasons.joins(:project).where("projects.updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))

    # Get all non deleted objects when logging in from mobile app
    else
      reasons = reasons.where(deleted: false)
    end

    render json: reasons
  end
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your post, but why you don't try next: `reasons.joins(:project).where("reasons.updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))` ?

Comment: `reasons = reasons.joins(:project).where("projects.updated_at > ? AND reasons.updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))` - try this as where clause should have condition to check with `updated_at` attributes of both `projects` and `reasons` table.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you for that both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fetching `projects.updated_at`, but if I understood you right you need to fetch `reasons.updated_at`

```
reasons = reasons.joins(:project).where("reasons.updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))
```

produses that output for me

```
GET http://localhost:3000/reasons/index?updated_at=2016-05-04T06:43:19.280Z

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "R2",
        "project_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:19.280Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:19.280Z",
        "deleted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "R3",
        "project_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:25.895Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:25.895Z",
        "deleted": false
    }
]
```

And without any filter

```
GET http://localhost:3000/reasons/index

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "R1",
        "project_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:11.044Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:11.044Z",
        "deleted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "R2",
        "project_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:19.280Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:19.280Z",
        "deleted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "R3",
        "project_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:25.895Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-04T06:43:25.895Z",
        "deleted": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just changing to reasons.updated_at, thanks!

```
reasons = reasons.joins(:project).where("reasons.updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))
```